# Excel VBA - Reading notepad file after nth characther

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code that can read the first 2 character of the notepad file. Below are the code:

```
Public Sub extractInt()

   Dim sText As String

   Open "C:\ProgramData\regid.512-06.com.system.microsoft\regid.512-06.com.system.microsoft.12606768.dat" For Input As #1

   sText = Input$(2, 1)

   Close #1

   Worksheets("ED").Range("C01").Value = sText

End Sub
```

It is working good however now i would like to read after 6th character.

For example if the string in the notepad file is :

```
"abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
```

I would like to read `"hijkl"`.

hope you guys can give some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the arguments of `Input$` and use `Right` :

`Input$(Number_of_Chars_To_Return, [#]NumFile)`
`Right(String,Number_of_Chars_From_the_Right)`

```
Public Sub extractInt()

   Dim sText As String

   Open "C:\ProgramData\regid.512-06.com.system.microsoft\regid.512-06.com.system.microsoft.12606768.dat" For Input As #1

   sText = Right(Input$(11, #1), 5)

   Close #1

   Worksheets("ED").Range("C01").Value = sText

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Mid` function to handle this, by first reading the string inside your text file to `sText` variable.

Afterwards, use the `Mid` function with:

```
sText = Mid(sText, 7, Len(sText) - 6)
```

`Mid` function explanation: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx)

**Code**

```
Public Sub extractInt()

    Dim sText As String

    Open "C:\ProgramData\regid.512-06.com.system.microsoft\regid.512-06.com.system.microsoft.12606768.dat" For Input As #1
    Input #1, sText
    sText = Mid(sText, 7, Len(sText) - 6)

    Close #1
    Worksheets("ED").Range("C01").Value = sText
End Sub
```

Comment: hi shai rado. it is working but not as expected result. The below answer gave answer as expected. Thanks for the info.